# wso2 api for API Publisher and API Store throws error

Tags: api, wso2

I have successfully installed WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 BAM. I can access my IP::9443/publisher/, IP:9443/stores/, IP:9443/carbon/ and :9444/publisher/ application from browser. 
I'm trying to access the publishers and stores via APIs in order to have this available for customers. I'm referring the documentation for it at http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Publisher+APIs but when I try to hit my application with

curl -X POST -c cookies `http://IP:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag` -d 'action=login&username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD'

it gives output as below
{"error" : false}

and I see following in cookie file.

---

# cat cookies
 # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
 # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
 # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk

### # HttpOnly_IP_HERE  FALSE   /publisher/     FALSE   0       JSESSIONID      XYZ_SESSION_ID_HERE

I couldnt find any article related to this so posting it here. I tried the same for /stores too and it also failing with the same messeage. Am I missing something to get this working? Appreciate any resolution if any one is aware of.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue here.  {"error" : false} means No error. The login is Successful. If there is any issue the response will be different and error message will include in the response with error:true.

You can call the publisher API after this. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Well, I tried the next call for the /store api after that. e.g. curl -X POST -c cookies http://IP:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'        which returns {"error" : false}   and then curl -b cookies http://IP:9763/store/site/blocks/api/listing/ajax/list.jag?action=getAllPublishedAPIs that also returns as {"error" : false} Isnt that suppose to return all the publisged APIs?

Comment: I even tried curl -b cookies http://IP:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-list/ajax/subscription-list.jag?action=getAllSubscriptions&username=admin" which returns as {"subscriptions" : null, "error" : false} even though admin is subscribed to few apis when I check from browser.